# Utilizar rescrita de URL como array no .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

É possível utilizar a rescrita com .htaccess e um número indefinido de parâmetros na URL?

No meu .htaccess atual eu defini três tipos de parâmetros que poderão ser passados na URL (/page/sub/id), porém eu gostaria de poder passar um número ilimitado de parâmetros e que eles seguissem uma ordem como em um array (/1/2/3/4/...), é possível?

Meu .htaccess atual:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

Dúvida: é possível fazer isso sem ter que fazer alguma "maneira alternativa" utilizando `explode()` por exemplo?

Comment: Não compreendi.

Comment: Redirecione qualquer endereço para uma página tipo `seletor.php?parametros` e faça a divisão das barras no PHP e não no htaccess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma possível saída é mandar todos os endereços para o mesmo PHP:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

E nesse PHP, dividir e processar os caminhos conforme necessário:

```
<?php

   $caminho = $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"];
   $pastas = explode( '/', $caminho );

   // demonstracapo
   print_r( $pastas );

?>
```

Se preferir trocar `index.php/$1` por `index.php?$1` ou similares também dá, mas o caminho virá no lugar da `QUERY_STRING`.

Eu particularmente prefiro a barra, pois aí os parâmetros de `$_GET[]` vão funcionar normalmente.

EDIT: Como o OP prefere uma solução pura com `.htaccess`, vou deixar esta apenas como referência para quem tenha interesse em usar este caminho.

Notando que esta solução funciona inclusive pra quem não tem como mexer no `.htaccess`, bastando por o PHP no path desta forma:

```
example.com/api.php/barcode/289163753
```

Comment: Acredito que desta forma seja ruim, pois o $_GET deixa de funcionar. Minha dúvida é: é possível fazer isso sem precisar utilizar explode(), apenas com .htaccess?

Comment: Sim, eu li muito bem e acredito que funcione sim, porem gostaria de saber se é possível utilizando apenas .htaccess que acredito que seja a forma correta de fazer, caso não, a sua resposta será muito útil.

Comment: Neste caso depende de cada página do sistema proceder a informação conforme o necessário, mas seguirá um padrão como por exemplo: /pagina_principal/sub_pagina/produtos/id/parametro1/parametro2/

Comment: Imaginei que fosse coisa do tipo. Não consigo imaginar onde você teria muito ganho evitando o explode (o `.htaccess` usa _regex_, que tente a ser bem "pior" que `explode` em termos de complexidade algoritmica), mas vamos torcer pra aparecerem mais opções de resposta (que é o legal do site, de uma pergunta podem sair várias opções legais). Preciso sair, mas repenso no assunto mais tarde (e vejo as novidades).

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção que você pode fazer é definir o `.htaccess` da seguinte forma.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Onde será passado para o arquivo `index.php` no parâmetro `url`

No `index.php` você recupera da seguinte forma:

```
$url = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
```

E ai fica a cargo teu definir a ordem de quem é quem. Ex.:

```
$url[0]//controller
$url[1]//action
$url[2]//parametro1
$url[3]//parametro3
```

Comment: Sim, a mesma coisa.